# Many to many relation filter

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, notin

I have the following tables:

```
user (id, firstname, lastname)

follow (id, follower_id, following_id)
```

Now imagine we have users with id 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

And `user_id = 1` already following user 2 and 3.

Now I want to write a query that gives me the `user_id's` that I `(user_id = 1)` am not following which are (4 and 5).

Can someone please help.

Comment: Did you tried any of the solutions?

Comment: Yes, The best one I would say is the one with the most votes.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT id FROM user 
WHERE 
    id NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT following_id 
        WHERE follower_id = 1 --(or you can use any user i, i used 1 to show an example)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user_table
LEFT JOIN follow_table ON user_table.id = follow_table.following_id
WHERE follow_table.following_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_table ut
LEFT JOIN follow_table ft ON ut.id = ft.following_id AND ft.follower_id = 1
WHERE ft.following_id IS NULL
```